# PHP variable assignment is treated as reference

Tags: php, variables, reference

We have the following code:

```
$fruits = array(
    (object) array(
        'name' => 'orange',
        'country' => 'brazil',
        'qty' => 23,
        'destination' => 'romania'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'name' => 'pinapple',
        'country' => 'thailand',
        'qty' => 3,
        'destination' => 'germany'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'name' => 'carrot',
        'country' => 'romania',
        'qty' => 250,
        'destination' => 'france'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'name' => 'bannana',
        'country' => 'kenya',
        'qty' => 50,
        'destination' => 'sweden'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'name' => 'melon',
        'country' => 'romania',
        'qty' => 50,
        'destination' => 'uae'
    )
);

function testing($fruits)
{
    for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($fruits); $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        $fruit = $fruits[$i];
        $fruits[$i]->qty = $fruit->qty * 100;

        unset($fruit->destination);
        unset($fruit->test);
        unset($fruit->country);
    }

    return $fruits;
}

var_dump($fruits);

testing($fruits);

var_dump($fruits);

?>
```

If you run that code, the $fruits array has its items changed since it's passed as reference.

The question is: how can we pass it so that the testing() function does not alter the $fruits?

Thanks to all.

Comment: **clone** your object

Comment: Make a copy of the array, then do your operation on the copy. One thing I noticed is what are you casting?

Comment: Yes we are casting for this example. The actual code is different but follows the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

What about cloning your objects ?

```
$clone = array();

foreach ($fruits as $k => $v) {
    $clone[$k] = clone $v;
}
testing($clone);
```